# Virtual environment and git

Tags: git, virtualenv

So I created a new remote git repository and also had a venv folder in there , thought of using .gitignore to untrack the folder , but when I checked git status the file was untracked by default( returned clean working tree nothing to commit ). I would like to know why it's so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move inside your virtualenv directory. There will already be a `.gitignore` file which excludes it from git.